# JPA Repository and constructor with varargs

Tags: java, hibernate, spring-boot, jpa, variadic-functions

It is possible to use constructor of varargs in @Query (org.springframework.data.jpa.repository). What I mean is class like this:

```
public class EntityDTO {

  public EntityDTO(Long id, LocalDate... dates) {
    // some code here where dates 
    //which are converted to List<Pair<LocalDate, LocalDate> datesList
  }
}

public interface CustomRepository extends JpaRepository<Entity, Long> {

  @Query("SELECT new package.path.EntityDTO(id, date1, date2, date2) FROM Entity")
  List<EntityDTO> findEntityList();
}
```

Now there is an error like this:

```
Unsatisfied dependency expressed through constructor parameter 3
 Validation failed for query for method public abstract java.util.List CustomRepository.findEntityList(java.lang.Long,java.time.LocalDate,java.time.LocalDate)

Caused by: org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.QuerySyntaxException: 
 Unable to locate appropriate constructor on class [EntityDTO]. Expected arguments are: long, java.time.LocalDate, java.time.LocalDate, java.time.LocalDate, java.time.LocalDate
```

It is only query example because dto can have id and LocalDate parameter from 2 to 12-14 in constructor, dates can be from different tables (entities). It depends from query. I want class more generic for this purpose. Query is much more complicated than in this example but I'm interested in some kind of constructor which give me possibility to create something similar that I described in EntityDTO constructor in comment. It is possible to use varargs in `@Query`?

Edit:
Do you have any suggestion what could I use if JPQL don't have this functionality?

Comment: Why not overload the constructor? or use a List as parameter?

Comment: How would you use list in JPQL? Because I don't know the way to map something like that. Inner constructor of list in EntityDTO in @Query is not working. Yes. I know that I could use overloaded constructor but I would have something about 14 constructors.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm afraid that's impossible.

The way Hibernate implements matching constructor resolution, only constructors with the exact same number of arguments as the number of parameters passed into the constructor expression are considered potential matches.

A workaround *could* be to create a constructor that accepts a list and then modify your query to something along the lines of `SELECT NEW EntityDTO(id, NEW list(date1, date2, date2))`... if only nested `NEW` expressions were supported. Unfortunately, this is a long standing [feature request](https://hibernate.atlassian.net/browse/HHH-37).